# Div expand to size of absolutely positioned content

Tags: css

I have a Div which contains a few absolutely positioned divs. The clickable area of the top level expands to the area of the children, but the drawn area does not. I want the drawn area to surround all the container divs.

A JSFiddle of the code is here - http://jsfiddle.net/VolatileStorm/C29P8/

After a few refreshes you may notice a small red box in the top left corner (hidden by the divs). This is the container, and I want it to surround the children.

Any ideas? Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you've already got a JS option, I'll give you one using CSS. It may come across as something of a hack, but it works: http://jsfiddle.net/C29P8/131/

The idea is to remove all positioning elements, set the ".pile" container to `float: left;`, which expands it to fit the content (also set the notes to `float: left;` as they have no positioning), and shift the notes, using `margin-left: -100px;` in ".note" and `padding-left: 110px` (the extra 10px of padding simply allows for the rotation of the note, keeping it within the red border) in ".pile" so that each note is drawn on top of each other.

I'm not brilliant at explaining it, sorry, so I've commented the code I've added and changed on the JSFiddle page, which should hopefully be clearer.

Comment: This confuses me, but it does work and it lets the browser take care of the bounding (and the browser is probably better at that than me).
Does anyone have any idea how this works? I'd suggest that the browser attempts to float left and, noticing the margin, thinks that there's nothing there, when in fact there is?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely positioned elements get taken out of the flow of the page, so either you can use JS to read the dimensions of the children to set those of the parent, or just set a height & width on your relative div.

Comment: Maybe set the height and width a little larger than the elements to account for corners that are sticking out.

Answer (score 2):

Find out the actual width you need by using `getBoundingClientRect()`.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/C29P8/137/.